# how to take information from custom method and apply it to another method inside my constructor function javascript?

Tags: javascript

Okay so I was trying to think of a good example, and so I created a constructor function about precious metals.  The constructor takes in type of metal and weight.  I have two methods.  One method determines if the precious metal (gold or silver) is real and the other calculates the value based on spot price.  (I know the spot price is wrong, this is just an example anyway).

Suppose a customer brought in a silver piece that is 80% silver.  Because its 80% silver I want to apply that to my metalValue method.  How would I do that.

Here is the code.  (JSFiddle provided for your convience http://jsfiddle.net/bwj3fv12/).
This will help me understand constructors better.

HTML

```
<div id="testDiv">test Div</div>
<div id="testDiv2">test Div2</div> <br /><br />
```

JavaScript

```
var PreciousMetals = function(metal, weight){
    this.metal = metal;
    this.weight = weight;  //weight in ounces

    this.authentic = function(colorTest){
        var metalPurity;
        var zero = "";
        if (this.metal == "silver"){
            switch(colorTest){
                case "brightred":
                    metalPurity = 1;
                    break;
                case "darkred":
                    metalPurity = 0.925;
                    break;
                case "brown":
                    metalPurity = 0.80;
                    break;
                case "green":
                    metalPurity = 0.50;
                    break;
                default:
                    metalPurity = 0;
            }


        }else if(this.metal == "gold"){
            switch(colorTest){
               case "green":
                   metalPurity = "base metal or gold plated";
                   break;
               case "milk colored":
                   metalPurity = "gold plated sterling silver";
                   break;
               case "no color":
                   metalPurity = "real gold";
                   break;
               default:
                   metalPurity = "Could be a fake, try different test";
            }
        }
        return metalPurity;
    }

    this.metalValue = function(metal){
        var sum = 0;
        var spotPrice;
        if (this.metal == "gold"){
           spotPrice = 1000;
        }else if(this.metal == "silver"){
           spotPrice = 15;
        }
        sum = spotPrice * this.weight;
        return sum;        
    }
}


var customerCindy = new PreciousMetals("silver", 2);

document.getElementById('testDiv').innerHTML = customerCindy.authentic("brown");


document.getElementById('testDiv2').innerHTML = customerCindy.metalValue();  //The result I would like would be 24 of course.
```

Now I realize I could do it this way:

```
document.getElementById('testDiv2').innerHTML = customerCindy.metalValue() * customerCindy.authentic("brown");
```

However the goal here is to take in the information from the authentic method and use that to help me calculate the metal Value in the metalValue method.

Comment: Also I could rewrite the constructor to where I only need one method and achieve the results I need, again however I just want to know if it is possible to take the result of one method and apply to another method.  If I had to create a program like this, I would just do all this in one method, but again that doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to keep the logic of these two methods separate in your constructor function, you could include a third method that performs the task of multiplying the two results.

```
var PreciousMetals = function(metal, weight){
    this.metal = metal;
    this.weight = weight;  //weight in ounces

    this.authentic = function(colorTest){
        var metalPurity;
        var zero = "";
        if (this.metal == "silver"){
            switch(colorTest){
                case "brightred":
                    metalPurity = 1;
                    break;
                case "darkred":
                    metalPurity = 0.925;
                    break;
                case "brown":
                    metalPurity = 0.80;
                    break;
                case "green":
                    metalPurity = 0.50;
                    break;
                default:
                    metalPurity = 0;
            }


        }else if(this.metal == "gold"){
           switch(colorTest){
                case "green":
                    metalPurity = "base metal or gold plated";
                    break;
                case "milk colored":
                    metalPurity = "gold plated sterling silver";
                    break;
                case "no color":
                    metalPurity = "real gold";
                    break;
                default:
                    metalPurity = "Could be a fake, try different test";
            }
        }
        return metalPurity;
    }

    this.metalValue = function(){
        var sum = 0;
        var spotPrice;
        if (this.metal == "gold"){
           spotPrice = 1000;
        }else if(this.metal == "silver"){
           spotPrice = 15;
        }
        sum = spotPrice * this.weight;
        return sum;        
    }

    this.netValue = function(colorTest){
        return this.authentic(colorTest) * this.metalValue();    
    }
}
```

Here's a working JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/bwj3fv12/

Comment: Yeah, that is what I figured, and I thought about something like that.  So I guess maybe it is not possible to take the result of a method and apply to another method.

Comment: Technically you could do the following (not ideal):

document.getElementById('testDiv1').innerHTML = customerCindy.metalValue(customerCindy.authentic("brown"));

But you'd still need to modify this.metalValue similar to Scott's suggestion below, like so:

    this.metalValue = function(purity){
        var sum = 0;
        var spotPrice;
        if (this.metal == "gold"){
           spotPrice = 1000;
        }else if(this.metal == "silver"){
           spotPrice = 15;
        }
        sum = spotPrice * this.weight * purity;
        return sum;        
    }

Comment: JSFiddle for this less than ideal solution to pass values between methods: https://jsfiddle.net/rjatkinson2/bwj3fv12/1/

Comment: It's less than ideal because of strange design choices about what is stored as an instance property and what is simply passed in as a method parameter.  There's nothing particularly odd about the way the methods are calling one another.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to update `metalValue` to include the results from the purity check, you could just update

```
this.metalValue = function(colorTest){
    // ...
    sum = spotPrice * this.weight * this.authentic(colorTest);
    return sum;        
}
```

and call it with

```
customerCindy.metalValue('brown');
```

Since this is just an example, there's no reason to worry about it, but presumably the purity in the real world would be just as much an instance property as the metal and the weight, and wouldn't actually be a transient value for a method like this.  But that's neither here nor there.

Comment: I realize Scott its a poor example for the real world, lol, sorry.  I was just trying to think of a good one and I guess this is all I could muster up.  Thanks though, works good.